# HTTP trigger azure function with blob output binding

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I need to save my HTTP message to the blob. I am using the below code. the file is getting created but without content. I need the XML data to be stored in the blob

```
[FunctionName("Function11")
public static async Task <IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, 
    [Blob("Order/sales_{Datetimenow}.xml", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream outputStream)
{ 
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(requestBody); 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is not a great fit. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, and explicitly this part

```cs
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
return new OkObjectResult(requestBody);
```

it shows that you are...

1. reading the body of the POST
2. putting the body in the `requestBody` variable
3. returning an `OkObjectResult` with `requestBody` as the content

What you are NOT doing is writing the body to the `outputStream`. You should either create a `StreamWriter` and write to the stream, otherwise there's nothing to be written to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

[FunctionName("HTTPTrigger")]
public static async Task RunAsync(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
[Blob("sample/order{DateTime.now}.xml", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream oStream, ILogger log)
{

```
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        oStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));
        return new OkObjectResult(requestBody);
```